# what is the use of makeView() method in ImageSwitcher

Tags: android, imageswitcher

I created a simple ImageSwitcher which implements the ViewFactory. And in the example i have seen, there is a makeView() method which is not called explicitly, but if the method is not present it shows the errors. Can anyone explain me the purpose of this method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to comply with the ViewFactory specification, we need to write a
makeView method. When you create a ImageSwitcher control, you can configure ViewFactory using the setFactory() method. ViewFactory has one required method, the makeView() method. Note that the source, or contents, of the view have not been configured in the makeView() method. Instead, you can consider this a template that the ImageSwitcher control will use to display each child view.